# Multiple Tables in One - Misalignment

Tags: html, css

**EDIT**: I did not construct this table myself. A table absolutely shouldn't be constructed this way and is a fix I'm implementing in the future. But the back-end code unfortunately depends on this exact table structure-each inner table has it's own class names and id's and trigger functions, etc.

I've got this problem working with a table made up of multiple tables - One table is the table itself, another table makes up the header, or `<thead>`, and another table makes up the `<tbody>`-there are also divs within the table cells (`<td>`) it looks like this:

```
<div id="myTableContainer">
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <table id="myTableHeader">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>Header Data 1</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>Header Data 2</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <table id="myTableData">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>Table Data 1</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>Table Data 2</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that there's some javascript working in the background to resize these table cells based on how much text is in them, but I can't align the header cells with the with the rows below them properly with CSS. I've experimented with the `table-layout` property and giving each `td` a max/min-width, but I'm stuck as to getting all the data & columns aligned because if many columns are created, the table gradually mis-aligns. What's more, both the inner tables are generated dynamically, so it's not as simple as restructuring the table as a whole. This table has proved very difficult to work with as it was developed for IE5 or 6 (works in Quirks mode all the way)

Does anyone have any ideas or sure-fire solutions on how to align this table properly? Preferably a CSS-based solution?

If you can't picture it, my table basically looks like this (and gets gradually worse if more columns are inside of it)

[image]

I hope I explained this well enough, if more info is needed I will provide

Comment: You don't have to create another table in <thead>. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Learn to use `thead`, `tfoot` and`tbody`; in that order and instead of `tr` use `th` in `thead` and `tfoot`. Never put a `table` in another `table` either. The only valid attributes you should use on a `table` element should be `id` and `summary`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have `<table>` tags inside `<thead>` and `<tbody>`.  Your code should just look like this:

```
<div id="myTableContainer">
    <table id="myTable" border="1">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>Header Data 1</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>Header Data 2</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>Table Data 1</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>Table Data 2</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It absolutely should and is a fix I'm implementing in the future. But the back-end code unfortunately depends on this exact table structure. Each inner table has it's own class names and id's

Comment: can you put the ids on thead and tbody instead?  or edit some of the back end code?

Comment: It will take some time as these tables are auto-generated with <xsl:template>'s. I was looking for a quick and dirty styling solution because I've tried about everything.

Comment: maybe, after the back end does its thing, you can just create a new table with JS that has the right structure, and use it to replace that other PITA table.

Comment: Ha! You have no idea. I'm still trying to find the guy who made this thing and ask "WHY"

Comment: hopefully that guy is no longer a developer.  =)

Answer (score 1):

I would correct the old code but in case you don't intend to, look for below hack:

I cannot think of a pure CSS solution. But how about CopyCSS (http://upshots.org/javascript/jquery-copy-style-copycss)?

You can call your copyCSS (you can selectively copy only width property). Question is how to detect if width of column changes?

For that you will have to take help of onresize event (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp). For that you have to dynamically add onResize event to at least first row of your second (i.e. inside ) table.